# Link on mobile app notification broken?

Tags: bug, mobile

I've just opened SE mobile app (Android) and I've got this notification:

[image]

"*You've been around for a while; see vote counts*" definitely looked like a link, so I tried to tap it.
The whole row highlights in yellow when I tap it, but nothing else happens.

Further infos:

- I've tried to kill the app and relaunch it and it happens again.
- The app is updated to the latest version.
- I'm using Android 4.4.4 on a Nexus 5.